# When importing a CSV with Scala in Spark, date shows as null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a simple task of importing a CSV and then filtering the data on date. I started with just converting the string into a date and I can't even seem to get that far. I've used some code samples from others work but it keeps failing. When I run the following, I get nothing but NULL. Dates look like this in the file: 8/29/2013 12:06. The ultimate goal here is to filter by date. Do you even need to cast the string as a date before you do that? I would assume so..

```
package net.massstreet.hour10

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._
import java.text._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object TempTest {



  def main(args: Array[String]) {

     Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Use new SparkSession interface in Spark 2.0      
    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("BayAreaBikeAnalysis")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp") // Necessary to work around a Windows bug in Spark 2.0.0; omit if you're not on Windows.
    .getOrCreate()

    //Load files into data sets
    import spark.implicits._
    val stations = spark.read.format("CSV").option("header","true").load("Data/station.csv")
    stations.select(to_date($"installation_date")).show()
    spark.stop()
  }   



}
```

Comment: `to_date` only parses a particular format, otherwise it's NULL

Comment: And no, you can filter strings just as easily as dates

Comment: Ok then let me treat the filtering as a different question. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Well, I would like to answer with the correct usage of `to_date()`, which I don't know immediately. But, it makes sense that it can't detect any possible date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you even need to cast the string as a date before you do that?

Nope. But, if you did, you'll need to parse `8/29/2013 12:06` yourself.

For example,

```
unix_timestamp($"installation_date"), "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm").cast("timestamp")
```